# MSSQL Server Function with uniqueidentifier as return value

Tags: sql-server, function, return-value, uniqueidentifier

I have got an table for each User, in which his history is stored. Now i need a function, which get the last action of this user. Here is my attempt.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLastUserActionID]
(
    @userID uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS uniqueidentifier
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @actionID uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(max)
    Set @tableName = '[tbl_History' + convert(nvarchar(36), @userID) + ']'
    SELECT @actionID = Top(1) his_ID from @tableName ORDER BY his_Date desc
    RETURN @actionID
END
```

this line the Server does not like at all:

```
SELECT @actionID = Top(1) his_ID from @tableName ORDER BY his_Date desc
```

the "Top(1)" is marked. Perhaps somebody know a alternative suggestion to achieve my goal?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: sorry I thought I have already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this the other day. Try writing the line like

```
SELECT Top 1 @actionID =  his_ID from @tableName ORDER BY his_Date desc
```

Comment: It worked fine, but now I have the next problem. ;-) the server tells me, that I have to define "@table" first. I will work on that now. Thank you for help!

Comment: It looks like you set your temp table up as an NVarchar.. you need to set that variabke up as a table.. like so.

DECLARE @table TABLE 
( 
    id INT, 
    name VARCHAR(32) 
)

Comment: Here is an article to check out on that

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html